# invalid character javascript error while using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to convert a `json` string to object format read from a `.js` file.

Below is the `JSON` string in `document.js`

```
    [
     {
       "type": "TableShape",
       "id": "63c0f27a-716e-804c-6873-cd99b945b63f",
       "x": 80,
       "y": 59,
       "width": 99,
       "height": 107,       
       "name": "Group",
       "entities": [
         {
           "text": "id",
           "id": "49be7d78-4dcf-38ab-3733-b4108701f1"
         },
         {
           "text": "employee_fk",
           "id": "49be7d78-4dcf-38ab-3733-b4108701fce4"
         }
       ]
     }
   ];
```

now i am calling the `document.js` in `window load` using `AJAX` like below

```
 $(window).load(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "JS/Draw2d/SampleData/document.js",
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    jsonStringFromServer = JSON.parse(result);//Here Javascript error stating invalid character 
                    alert(jsonStringFromServer);
                }
            });           
        });
```

Comment: Try removing the `;` at the end of the JSON string in `document.js`

Comment: you can use this site to validate your json http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: That solved the problem. TQ

Answer (score 0):

When the `$.ajax` function receives JSON, it automatically deserialises it for you. The error you're seeing is being cause because you're passing an object to `JSON.parse`, not a JSON formatted string - you don't need to use `JSON.parse` at all. Try this:

```
success: function (result) {
    debugger;
    console.log(result); // = the received object
}
```

I would also strongly suggest you remove `async: false` as it is extremely bad practice to use it.

Comment: As an aside, `result` is only automatically deserialized if the correct `Content-Type` header is returned. Otherwise you need to add the `dataType: json` parameter to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion i will follow that and i really want to know is there any way to write a some JSON text to a .txt file?